# Set Scatterplot Marker size after plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

Need little help here. How can you change markersize of scatterplot after plotting?
For example, let's say I have the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

a = list(range(20))
b = list(range(20, 40))
p = ax.scatter(a, b)
```

I did not set 's' while plotting. I want to do it, say, after.
FYI, I tried *plt.setp(p, s=10)* but to no avail.

Appreciate if you can explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `ax.scatter` is a [`matplotlib.collections.PathCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection). Therefore there are many arguments you can use. One of them is [`set_sizes()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.set_sizes):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

a = list(range(20))
b = list(range(20, 40))
p = ax.scatter(a, b)

p.set_sizes([10])
```

This also allows you to set different of sizes, so long as the list is the same length as the number of scatter points.

```
p.set_sizes(range(20))
```

[image]

Comment: shoot, how could I miss it in the documentation... You are free to reply RTFM :) Thanks @DavidG

Comment: @user2968773 No problem. Sometimes they're easy to miss :-) don't forget to upvote/accept the best answer that solves your problem to mark the question as solved

Comment: Done. thanks  @DavidG

Comment: Why would you beg for acceptance or upvotes on answers to duplicates?
 Such answers shouldn't be there in the first place, but if you decide to provide such an answer, what is the purpose of voting on it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I marked as best answer, because he could stand my ignorance, and find a will to reply, just like you did pinpoint it was a duplicate.

Comment: I didn't beg, I said the "best" answer not "my"/"this" answer. I didn't see the duplicate before posting. I can delete if you like

Comment: You asked to accept/vote, 8 minutes *after* it was marked as duplicate.

Comment: Did I? Oh yeah... I honestly did not see that it was marked as duplicate when I wrote that and didn't refresh the page either